# Looking for example of a linearly ordered (but not well-ordered) transitive set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

In [*The Foundations of Mathematics*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Foundations_of_Mathematics/_B_oQQAACAAJ?hl=en) (p.33), Kenneth Kunen gives the following definitions:

> **Definition I.8.1** $z$ *is a* transitive set *iff* $\forall{y}\in\ z[y\subseteq{z}]$*; equivalently,* $\forall{xy}[x\in{y}\ \wedge\ y\in{z}\to\ x\in{z}]$.
>
> **Definition I.8.2** $z$ *is a (von Neumann) ordinal iff* $z$ *is a transitive set and* $z$ *is well-ordered by* $\in$.

I would like to see an example of a *linearly ordered*<sup>1</sup> (but not well-ordered) transitive set.

(To make this example set most directly comparable to a von Neumman ordinal, I imagine that the order relation should be $\in$.)

---

<sup>1</sup> By *linearly ordered* I mean that the order relation on the set is irreflexive and satisfies trichotomy (i.e. for all $x, y$ in the relation's field, either $x < y$, $x = y$, or $x > y$).

Comment: The axiom of foundation implies this is impossible.

Comment: @MarkSaving: I suppose that your point applies only to the case where the order relation is $\in$.  In other words, the Axiom of Foundation would not rule some other linear order.  That's my understanding, anyway.  Also, if the Axiom of Foundation guarantees that $\in$ is automatically well-founded, then why explicitly include well-orderedness in the definition of ordinals?  In other words, why not define an ordinal simply as a transitive set that is totally ordered by $\in$?

Comment: Because it is useful when we do not assume the axiom of foundation. In particular, demonstrating many of the properties of this axiom requires the construction of the class of well-founded sets, which, in many treatments, is done using transfinite recursion (i.e. using ordinals).

Comment: If you don't insist that the order relation be $\in$, then it's easy.  Just map $\omega$ to $\Bbb Z$ and use the usual order on $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @RobertShore: I don't insist that the order relation be $\in$, but the set still needs to be transitive.  Your idea sounds intriguing to me, but I cannot fill in the details.  In particular, I have problems with the transitivity of proposed set.  (I suspect that the reason for the need to map $\omega$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ somehow relates to this transitivity requirement, but I cannot make a proper derivation from this.)  Would you mind posting your suggestion as a full answer?  (Please show that the proposed set is transitive.)

Comment: We're talking about the ordinal $\omega$, which I assume you know to be transitive (under $\in$).